# What noun would best describe holding space for someone going through something you've been through?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

This is not necessarily a spiritual connotation. If someone is doing something that pushes their limits and someone is 'guiding' or 'facilitating' that by holding space, holding their hand, walking alongside them through the activity, is there a noun other than guide or facilitator that could be used as a title for that person?

Comment: What is meant by "holding space"?

Comment: I have looked up synonyms and not found the right word. I hoped maybe someone might have an idea that I hadn't thought of yet. :)

Comment: 'Holding space' is a way of being present and walking a journey WITH someone without interrupting or changing their journey or process.

Comment: @CherylMedlin That is a very particular meaning of 'holding space' that I haven't heard before. Is that a common usage in some community that you read/write with? Mindfulness? Counseling? Some other?

Comment: [_companion_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/companion):  A person who shares the experiences of another, especially when these are unpleasant or unwelcome.

Comment: @Mitch I'd be curious to know the definition of holding space you have heard as this is the only explanation I am aware of. I learned and teach this meaning in coaching circles.

Comment: @CherylMedlin That's my point, I have no definition of 'holding space' already, I've never heard those two words together, especially in the general context you're thinking of. I hear them literally and think 'oh, you want a space for literally holding things with your hands or only slightly metaphorically like a holding pen, a temporary corral for animals or packages. What are 'coaching circles'? Is this like for personal trainers or life coaches? So this is sort of like personal counseling?

Comment: Are you looking for a word for the person helping you along or for the feeling/action of a temporary resting place? Are you looking for a synonym for 'holding space'? Wait...is that a noun like 'a holding space' or a verb like 'my counselor is holding space for me'?

Answer (score 1):

The English word '**paraclete**' is a transliteration of the Greek word παράκλητος, *parakletos*.

The Greek word, and therefore the English transliteration, means 'one who draws near' and it is used when someone is at hand in crisis. Literally, *para* means alongside and *kletos* means called.

> 1992   D. Pannick Advocates ii. 29   The proper performance of the function of a lawyer, according to the Supreme Court of Tennessee, ‘does not include a self-appointed role as a **paraclete**..under the guise of legal services and at a lawyer's compensation rate’.

[OED-3](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/137308?redirectedFrom=paraclete#eid)

There is an English word 'advocate' but that does not actually answer the OP. Advocacy is representation, not assistance.

Comment: Unfortunately, 'paraclete' is too deeply rooted in Christian theology to be useful in this context. But it's definitely on the right track. 'Advocate' has a very different usage. 'Facilitator' or 'guide' are the closest I've found, I just am not fond of either for my purposes. Thanks!

Comment: @CherylMedlin does that mean you want a word that is not associated already with Christianity? What if it is from other religions/cultures (e.g guru or sensei (though those are more like teacher than helping companion). Sherpa?

Comment: @CherylMedlin please add "not deeply rooted in Christianity" and any other restrictions into your question.

Comment: @Mitch, really, too deeply rooted in a specific culture or spirituality might not work for the context. It's not Christianity specifically. Guru is widely used outside of spiritual connotations. Sensei and Sherpa are culturally specific.

Comment: @CherylMedlin This is getting confusing. Can you edit your question to say explicitly what you -don't- want. Also, what is your specific context (both the cultural situation and even the specific sentence you want to state about it but with a blank for where you want this word.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a single word that matches your requirement exactly, but here are some that might be made to serve your purpose.

> [Supporter](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/supporter): n. 2) an adherent, follower, backer, or advocate

(maybe too generic?)

> [Mentor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mentor?s=t): n. 2) an influential senior sponsor or supporter.

... conveys the sense that the person has already been through the same process

> [Sponsor](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sponsor?s=t): n. 1) a person who vouches or is responsible for a person or thing.

... might also be good, because there is the additional connotation of a sponsor "a person who answers for an infant at baptism, making the required professions and assuming responsibility for the child's religious upbringing; godfather or godmother."

By analogy, the person who's holding space for someone is also a sponsor: a more senior member of the 'community' who's helping a new member. As a bonus, the word isn't too strongly connected to theology or religion in general usage. *Sponsor* is also used in [twelve step fellowships](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve-step_program) in almost exactly the way the question describes.

As an outside bet, there's also:

> Fellow traveller: n. 1 a companion on a journey

Answer (score -1):

*coadjutor or adjutant:
One who works together with another such as an assistant

Comment: Hello, eisus123. I'm not sure why your response drew a downvote, but I suspect that the problem is related to the absence of a source (and a link) to the definition of "coadjutor or adjutant" that you provide. Please consider either adding such a linked reference or replacing your definition with relevant dictionary definitions of the two words you suggest. Thanks!